# How do I randomly generate a number between 75 - 100%?

Tags: java, random, floor, ceil

I know how to do it between 0 and 100, but I can I set the floor?

This is how I do 0 - 100..

```
int randomNum = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generate a random number from 0 to 25 and add 75. :)

Answer (score 6):

```
int randomNum = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 25) + 75;
```

Answer (score 4):

Generate a number between 0 and 25 and then add 75.

Answer (score 3):

Do it between zero and 25 and add 75.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is answered already but correct answer did not have code snippet.  So here is a little code snippet:

```
int randomNum = 0;
Random ran = new Random();
randomNum  = ran.nextInt(25) + 75;
```

Comment: +1 for putting actual code for those of us that don't know it off the top of our heads